# Generate a 'closeness to center' matrix in numpy

Tags: numpy

I think this should be easy, but I'm not sure of an efficient way to do it.

I'd like to build a matrix in numpy that has the cityblock / manhattan closeness to the center of the matrix, in numpy, for any odd size.

For a size of 5, the output would be:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 1],
       [2, 3, 4, 3, 2],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]])
```

What's the best way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: I just made an edit. I actually think it makes most sense only for odd sizes. Thanks

Comment: Also, seems relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126853

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy and efficient with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
def closeness_manhattan(N):
    r = np.arange(N)
    a = np.minimum(r,r[::-1])
    return a[:,None] + a
```

Sample runs -

```
In [14]: closeness_manhattan(4)
Out[14]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0]])

In [15]: closeness_manhattan(5)
Out[15]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 1],
       [2, 3, 4, 3, 2],
       [1, 2, 3, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]])
```